# Uploading Project Assets to S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

What I'm wanting to accomplish is take the request and save each of the files to my local server in dedicated directories depending on the category the asset it belongs to. Then I want to send the url from the local storage to the database so it can save its temporary location so that when the user is redirected they can see the image immediately on the next page, but I also need to loop through the all images and save them to an S3 bucket and then update the database field with the url from s3 but also keeping the category of the asset.

Controller

```
foreach ($request->file('contract_asset') as $file) {
    $path = Storage::disk('local')->put(Carbon::now()->toDateString().'/roofing/projects/'.$project->id.'/contract-assets', $file, 'public');
    $project->addContractAsset('contract', $path);               
}

if ($request->hasFile('insurance_asset')) {
    foreach ($request->file('insurance_asset') as $file) {
        $path = Storage::disk('local')->put(Carbon::now()->toDateString().'/roofing/projects/'.$project->id.'/insurance-assets', $file, 'public');
        $project->addContractAsset('insurance', $path);                
    }
}

$files = Storage::allFiles(Carbon::now()->toDateString().'/roofing/projects/'.$project->id.'/');

dispatch(new ProcessRoofingProjectAssets($files, $project));
```

Job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Roofing;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Storage;

class ProcessRoofingProjectAssets implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $files;
    protected $project;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($files, $project)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        foreach ($this->files as $file) {
            $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('contract-assets', $file, 'public');
            $this->project->addContractAsset($path);  
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function addContractAsset($category, $asset)
{
    $contract_asset_urls = json_decode($this->contract_asset_urls, true);
    $contract_asset_urls[] = ['category' => $category, 'url' => $asset];
    $this->update([
        'contract_asset_urls' => json_encode($contract_asset_urls)
    ]);

    if ($category == 'approval') {
        event(new AssociationApprovalAssetUploaded($this));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what isn't working

Comment: I'm just confused on when I should be dispatching the Job. If I should be doing it when I am or if I should be doing in the inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I don't see any specific problem with the way that you're doing it. Just don't forget to remove the local file once you've executed `addContractAsset` in your job.

Comment: Well I think what I should do is have it find the asset in the json and update it with the new url. I don't know.

Comment: I really have no idea on what I'm doing with this.